# Is there a workaround for using ObjC static libraries in an iOS Framework?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, dynamic-linking

For whatever reason, Swift does not allow building as a static library, but we have a vendor who insists on delivering us static libraries.

I've tried using -AllLoad and -ObjC flags, but have not succeeded in compiling a framework linked with static libs.

In theory since ObjC does not link function pointers (do they link classes at runtime also?) is there a way to build the Swift library without linking to the static libs and load it in the app? Or is there a reliable way to compile a static library into a framework?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the library to be "Optional" in the "Link with Libraries" phase or mark it "weak" in the "Other Linker Flags".